# Why does this operation execute faster on CPU than GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I was reading the tensorflow official guide, there is one example to show Explicit Device Placement of the operations. In the example, why does CPU executed time is less than GPU? More usually, what kind of operation will be executed faster on GPU?

```py
import time

def time_matmul(x):
  start = time.time()
  for loop in range(10):
    tf.matmul(x, x)

  result = time.time()-start

  print("10 loops: {:0.2f}ms".format(1000*result))

# Force execution on CPU
print("On CPU:")
with tf.device("CPU:0"):
  x = tf.random.uniform([1000, 1000])
  assert x.device.endswith("CPU:0")
  time_matmul(x)

# Force execution on GPU #0 if available
if tf.test.is_gpu_available():
  print("On GPU:")
  with tf.device("GPU:0"): # Or GPU:1 for the 2nd GPU, GPU:2 for the 3rd etc.
    x = tf.random.uniform([1000, 1000])
    assert x.device.endswith("GPU:0")
    time_matmul(x)


### Output
# On CPU:
# 10 loops: 107.55ms
# On GPU:
# 10 loops: 336.94ms
```

Comment: It takes longer to send data to device and return it sometimes.

Comment: Is the specific GPU on Tensorflow's list of supported hardware? Also, what are the GPU and CPU specs? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thanks for your comments. I think it is on the list. Also, this is the official code sample.

Comment: @BryceWayne That make sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GPU has high memory bandwidth and a high number of parallel computation units. Easily parallelizable or data-heavy operations would benefit from GPU execution. As, for example, matrix multiplication involves a large number of multiplications and additions that can be done in parallel.

CPU has low memory latency (which becomes less important when you read a lot of data at once) and a rich set of instructions. It shines when you have to do sequential calculations (fibonachi numbers might be an example), have to make random memory reads often, have complicated control flow etc.

The difference in the official blog is due to the fact, that PRNG algorithms are typically sequential and can not utilize parallelized operations quiet efficiently. But this is in general. Latest CUDA version already has PRNG kernels and does outperform CPU on such tasks.

When it comes to the example above, on my system I got 65ms on CPU and 0.3ms on GPU. Furthermore, if I set sampling size to [5000, 5000] it becomes CPU:7500ms while for GPU it stays the same GPU:0.3ms. On the other hand fo [10, 10] it is CPU:0.18 (up to 0.4ms though) vs GPU:0.25ms. It shows clearly, that even *a single operation* performance depends on the **size of the data**.

Back to the answer. Placing operations on GPU might be beneficial for easily parallelizable operations that can be computed with a low number of memory calls. CPU, on the other hand, shines when it comes to a high number of low latency (i.e. small amount of data) memory calls. Additionally, not all operations can be easily performed on a GPU.